# Java array swap

Tags: java, arrays, swap

In my second array I am trying to swap my array numbers, but I don't know how to do it.

For example, in my first array numbers looks like this:

```
1.5 2.5 3.5 ....19.5 20.5
```

So in next array need look like this:

```
1.5 20.5 2.5 19.5 3.5 ....
```

I make it look like this:

```
20.5 19.5 ......3.5 2.5 1.5
```

And this is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double A[] = new double[20];
    int  i ;
    double K, C;

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.print("K=");
    try {
        K = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("input-output error");
        return;
    }

    Random r = new Random();
    i=0;
    if (K<=0){
        do{
        A[i]= r.nextDouble()*20;
        i++;
        }while (i<20);

    }else{ 
        i=2;
        A[0]=K;
            A[1]=K+1;
            do {
                A[i]= A[i-1]+A[i-2];

            i++;


        }while (i<20);
    }

        System.out.println("A:");
        for (i=0; i<20; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%.2f\t", A[i]);
            if (i==9) System.out.println();
            if (i==19) System.out.println();
        }


        for (i=1; i<10; i++) {
            C = A[i-1];
            A[i] = A[19-i];
            A[19-i] = C;
        }

        System.out.println("\nB:");
        for (i=0; i<20; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%.2f\t", A[i]);
            if (i==9) System.out.println();
            if (i==19) System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by swap? Do you mean reverse the array?

Comment: No, not reverse. But i need change so Array looks like this:
1.5 20.5 2.5 19.5 3.5 ....

Comment: This is nothing but reverse

Comment: @ Krists Logins For input `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8` what would be the output ?

Comment: Output: 1,8,2,7,3,6,4,5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not really "swapping", but swapping is a component of what you are doing.

You need two "indexes", one walking the array from front to back, the other walking from back to front.  When the two indices "meet in the middle" you're done.

Then your algorithm looks like:

1. move the front index towards the back (skip the front value)
2. swap the value at both indexes.
3. move the front index towards the back (get off the swapped value)
4. move the back index toward the front. (get off the swapped value)
5. move the back index towards the front (skip the back value)

repeat until the two indices meet in the middle.

No.  You won't get a code example.  This is just a bit too much like homework for that, but I hope this helps.